# How to add timestamps to existing records in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having a collection 'users' in MongoDB which contains multiple records without timestamps. I am using that collection with my node application and have set timestamps to true as shown:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
...
},{
    timestamps: true
});
```

I wanted to apply timestamps to the existing records and use it with my node application in future. If I make new fields 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt', will they work with my Mongoose schema? Or if there is any alternative way to achieve the task, please enlighten me as I am new to node and mongo in general.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I think this applies cannot affect the existing collections in the database, cause these fields are just a bunch of documents you inserting with existing/updating operations.

in MongoDB, everything is just a document and MongoDB does not care about data you store inside a collection, no validation here.so mongoose comes in for handling those validations and etc. if you change a schema in a collection it only effects to incoming requests from now on. but be careful if conflict fields happen, you will get an error for getting collections.

**in short answer: MongoDB does not know when data stored or edited**

but you can get timeStamp of creation in mongo ObjectId:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/index.html

Comment: That's wrong. When you insert a new document then by default MongoDB generates the `_id` field which is an `ObjectId`. This ObjectId includes a timestamp information, you can get it with [getTimestamp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/index.html)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ofc , but there is no record about updating time stamp